# Não insere com o input data vazio

Tags: php, html, mysql

No meu formulário tenho este campo:

```html
<h5><strong>Data da Visita</strong></h5></h5> <input type="date" id="DataVisita" name="DataVisita" />
```

Mas se ficar sem data não insere na tabela da base de dados, e eu quero que insira porque nem sempre tenho de colocar a data

Comment: Você colocou `not null` no campo data ao criar a tabela ?

Comment: Não, coloquei `default null`

Comment: Qual erro é lançado ao tentar inserir ?

Comment: Não dá erro, fica a linha vazia

Comment: Não salva no banco, e não dá nenhum erro ?

Comment: Não, como faço o `echo` desse input para ver o erro?

Comment: Posso ver o código PHP que valida o formulário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o campo está como "not null" no mysql, tera de preencher sempre esse campo. Altere na sua BD esse campo e o tipo de dados convém ser **Varchar** ou passe a variavél.

Altere também o seu campo e coloque assim:

```
<h5><strong>Data da Visita</strong></h5></h5> <input type="text" id="DataVisita" name="DataVisita" />
```

Se o seu intuito é ter o calendário, mantenha o tipo de input mas altere apenas na base de dados o campo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h5><strong>Data da Visita</strong></h5></h5> <input type="date" id="DataVisita" name="DataVisita" required="off" />
```

Adicione o REQUIRED="OFF"

Comment: Se colocar o `REQUIRED="OFF"` pede-me para preencher o campo